# Change button inner text on click in a function that hides/shows all elements with class

Tags: javascript, toggle, show-hide

Found a way to show/hide all elements with class, but I need to change the button text on click from Hide to Show, than back again from Show to Hide. This is my JS code so far:

```
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function() {
    var o = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
    for ( var i = 0; i < o.length; i++ ) {
        if (o[i].style.display == 'none') {
            o[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            o[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Works as expected, so it hides and shows the elements with class, but I am not able to add the inner text change for the button. This is my html:

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>First Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Second Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Third Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Based on your question, I've included a working example below. - It seems to work as you would like it to. I hope it's helped solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code, run the script below.

I took your button and targeted the innerHTML. More info [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function() {
    var o = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
    var btn = document.getElementById("hide");
    for ( var i = 0; i < o.length; i++ ) {
        if (o[i].style.display == 'none') {
            o[i].style.display = 'block';
            btn.innerHTML = "Hide";
        } else {
            o[i].style.display = 'none';
            btn.innerHTML = "Show";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>First Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Second Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Third Item</h3>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>Detail 1</li>
            <li>Detail 2</li>
            <li>Detail 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it;

```
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = function() {
var o = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
for ( var i = 0; i < o.length; i++ ) {
    if (o[i].style.display == 'none') {
        o[i].style.display = 'block';
        this.innerText='hide';
    } else {
        o[i].style.display = 'none';
        this.innerText='show';
    }
}
```

}